# Run a single hardhat test file

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, test

I have a few test files:

./test/ContractA.test.js

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("ContractA tests", function () {
  it("does function one", async function () {
    expect(await contractA.someFunc()).to.equal(something);
  });
  it("does function two", async function () {
    expect(await contractA.someOtherFunction()).to.equal(somethingOtherThing);
  });
});
```

./test/ContractB.test.js

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("ContractB tests", function () {
  it("does function one", async function () {
    expect(await contractB.someFunc()).to.equal(something);
  });
  it("does function two", async function () {
    expect(await contractB.someOtherFunction()).to.equal(somethingOtherThing);
  });
});
```

When I run `hardhat test` all the files run.

How Can I run all the tests in ContractA.test.js?

---

### Things I've Already Tried

`hardhat test ./test/ContratA.test.js` - this does not run any tests at all...

`hardhat test --grep "ContractA"` - also does not run any tests...

Comment: Did you try **npx hardhat test ./test/ContratA.test.js**

Answer (score 5):

```
$ yarn hardhat test ./test/ContratA.test.js
```

Should work as the command line helper message explains:

```
$ yarn hardhat test --help

    Usage: hardhat [GLOBAL OPTIONS] test [--bail] [--deploy-fixture] [--grep <STRING>] [--no-compile] [--no-impersonation] [--parallel] [...testFiles]
    POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS:
    
      testFiles     An optional list of files to test (default: [])
```

Comment: nope! this stills runs the other test files for me. WTF??

Comment: @Jim um.. what's your hardhat version?

Comment: In my experience, this will run only the desired test file

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that. You just need to put ".only" after that describe, that you want to run.
In your case:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe.only("ContractA tests", function () {   it("does function one", async function () {
    expect(await contractA.someFunc()).to.equal(something);   });   it("does function two", async function () {
    expect(await contractA.someOtherFunction()).to.equal(somethingOtherThing);   }); });
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. When I add .only all my other test files are still run.

Comment: Explaining once again: In my above answer, ".only" is to be used for single test case file which have more than one describe. Only that describe will work, which have .only in front of it. For different test case files you have to comment other ones, which you don't want to test.

Comment: This "answer" does not address my question at all. Please try again!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, try this

```
npx hardhat test ../test/ContratA.test.js
```

The difference between your command is the path is `../test/ContratA.test.js` not `./test/ContratA.test.js`

Answer (score 0):

`hardhat test ./test/ContractA.test.js` is correct. You misspelt `ContractA` in your original post (you were missing the **c** and ended up with `ContratA`)